# simulate click based on CSS path from Dom element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a mouse activities( mouse move, click scroll etc.) i want to record and playback the mouse activities. i have been recorded mousemove i want to simulate a click based on the CSS Path.

```
var cssPath = function(el) {
if (!(el instanceof Element)) return;
var path = [];
while (el.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
    var selector = el.nodeName.toLowerCase();
    if (el.id) {
        selector += '#' + el.id;
    } else {
        var sib = el, nth = 1;
        while (sib.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE && (sib = sib.previousSibling) && nth++);
        selector += ":nth-child("+nth+")";
    }
    path.unshift(selector);
    el = el.parentNode;
}
return path.join(" > ");
```

}

```
 html > body > div#div-id > div.site:nth-child(1) > div.clearfix > ul.choices > li:nth-child(5)
```

How can i trigger click based on the above CSS path or something else based on the DOM.

Please note that i, do not have any ID or name of the DOM element.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var liEl = $('div#div-id > div.site:eq(1) > div.clearfix > ul.choices > li:eq(5)').get(0);
var targetEl = el.target;
if( liEl === targetEl ) { 
    // same element
}
else {
    // not same element
}
```